# Overloading << operator ostream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why doesn't the line below work?

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& os, const char *c)
{
    os << c; // why does this line doesn't work?
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    const char *c = "Hi";
    std::cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question in your code (it wasn't at all obvious), and deleted my comment after I saw it. I made an edit; this should be a bit better. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& os, const char *c)` has already been overloaded in iostream.

Comment: +1 I totally missed the method name and was just staring at the line of code, lol...

Comment: Thanks. that explains the recursion.